# JavaScript Interacting with options

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I currently have a dropdown list... to finish blank sentences off.

The problem I have is  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Here is a snippet of my HTML

```
<section class="question-three">
                <h4>Question 3</h4>
                <ol>
                    <li>A partnership is a business entity 
                    <select id="selectionOne">
                        <option value="#">Please Select...</option>
                        <option value="sole trader">sole trader</option>
                        <option value="members">members</option>
                        <option value="shareholders">shareholders</option>
                        <option value="run">run</option>
                        <option value="limited company">limited company</option>
                        <option value="owned">owned</option>
                    </select>
                    by two ore more people who carry a business collectively with a view to making a profit.
                </li>
```

JavaScript

```
var dropDownList = {
    answers: ['sole trader', 'members', 'shareholders', 'run', 'limited company', 'owned'],
    checkAnswer: function() {
        var check = document.getElementById('selectionOne');

        if(check.options == dropDownList.answers[5]) {
            console.log('The answer is right!');
        } else {
            console.log('false')
        }
    }
};

dropDownList.checkAnswer();
```

Could anyone please help me?

Thank You

Comment: You want `if (check.value ==`

Comment: When are you running the function? Is it in an event handler?

Comment: It's working fine for me when I put it in a  jsbin, what order do you have your html and scripts? are you calling checkAnswer() after the dom is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You are not accessing the `value`. We also do not know when you trigger the event. You need to assign it after the select has rendered:

```js
var dropDownList = {
    answers: ['sole trader', 'members', 'shareholders', 'run', 'limited company', 'owned'],
    checkAnswer: function() {
        var check = document.getElementById('selectionOne');

        if(check.value == dropDownList.answers[5]) {
            console.log('The answer is right!');
        } else {
            console.log('false')
        }
    }
};
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("checkIt").onclick=function() {
    dropDownList.checkAnswer();
  }
  // or document.getElementById("selectionOne").onchange
}
```

```html
<section class="question-three">
                <h4>Question 3</h4>
                <ol>
                    <li>A partnership is a business entity 
                    <select id="selectionOne">
                        <option value="#">Please Select...</option>
                        <option value="sole trader">sole trader</option>
                        <option value="members">members</option>
                        <option value="shareholders">shareholders</option>
                        <option value="run">run</option>
                        <option value="limited company">limited company</option>
                        <option value="owned">owned</option>
                    </select>
                    by two ore more people who carry a business collectively with a view to making a profit.
                </li>
<button id="checkIt">Check</button>
```