# make a user friendly crossbrowser event handler checker

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, event-handling

i am not an experienced javascript programmer.I tried to answer a question here where i have addEventListener as my event handler in my answer.I was advised not to use addEventListener for that specific problem as it has some cross-browser issue.

[Link to that question  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901567/javascript-interacting-with-options/27901771#27901771)

Then something came to my mind to make a function which will deal with event handler compatibility issue.Though i've managed to make the function necessary to create a compatible event handler,but i can't manage to make it user friendly.I mean in my code i have made a function call at the end which invoke the function which add event handler to a button.But i want all the html elements i can have in my document will use this function to have proper event handler method.How can i do that.I hope i've described my problem properly

```js
var button=document.getElementById('btn');

function makeListener(elem,event,prefix){
    if(document.addEventListener){
       elem.addEventListener(event,function(e){
            alert('it has addEventListener method');
    });
 }else if(document.attachEvent){
        elem.attachEvent(prefix+event,function(e){
            alert('it has attachEvent method');
     }); 
 }else{
        add=prefix+event;
     elem.add=function(){
            alert('it has neither addEventListener nor attachEvent');
     }
 }
 
}
makeListener(window.button,'click','on');
```

```html
<input type='button' value='listener tester' id='btn'>
```

Comment: how about using jQuery?

Comment: i am not quite familiar with jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to create is called a [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill). There are many of those floating around.

Here is one from Jonathan Neal which polyfills `addEventListener`, `removeEventListener`, `dispatchEvent`, `CustomEvent`, and `DOMContentLoaded`.

https://github.com/jonathantneal/EventListener

```js
document.getElementById('myButton1').addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert('Polyfill: You clicked me!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jonathantneal/EventListener/master/EventListener.js"></script>
<button id="myButton1">Example using Polyfill</button>
```

EDIT: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ suggests this:

```
// IE8+
function addEventListener(el, eventName, handler) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
  } else {
    el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function(){
      handler.call(el);
    });
  }
}

addEventListener(el, eventName, handler);
```

EDIT2: Here's an example of how you could use it.

```js
(function () {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  var myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');
  var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

  addEventListener(myInput, 'keydown', myInputOnKeydownCallback);
  addEventListener(myButton, 'click', myButtonOnClickCallback);

  function myInputOnKeydownCallback() {
    myButton.style.backgroundColor = randomRGB();
    myDiv.textContent = myInput.value;
  }


  function myButtonOnClickCallback() {
    myInput.value = null;
    myButton.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    myDiv.textContent = null;
  }

  function randomRGB() {
    return 'rgb(' + random(0, 255) + ', ' +
      random(0, 255) + ', ' +
      random(0, 255) + ')';
  }

  function random(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
  }
  
})();
```

```html
<script>
  function addEventListener(el, eventName, handler) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
      el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
    } else {
      el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function(){
        handler.call(el);
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<input id="myInput"/>

<button id="myButton" style="background: black; color: white">Clear</button>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: @al-Zami But what did you think about the polyfill I suggested? (I now removed the jquery example)

Comment: There's lots of example here http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ of what you can do when you don't want all of jquery. For example there's a `function addEventListener(..){..}` similar to yours that you might like.

Comment: i was thinking if i can  create a module with this code which i can use in my projects.

Comment: @al-Zami: So what are you missing in my answer? As I see it, you can just place the `function addEventListener(..) {..}` in its own file and include in your projects? I just added a usage example at the end of my answer.